# Iteration over var type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, anonymous-function

I have the following method, I select some values from database, return dataset and then show in dataGridView. I used Linq to DataSet to filter some values from DataSet, all work fine before I tried to iterate over var variable with values from L2D. This foreach:

**foreach (var valor in resultado)**

When the program execution comes to this foreach exit from the current method without pass by return statement.

Anyone know why this is happen?

```
 public static DataSet prestamosVencidos()
 {
        .....

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

       List<string> prestamosID = new List<string>();            

       query = BD.select()

        ds = bd.select(query);

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (!prestamosID.Contains(dr["prestamo_id"].ToString()))
            {
                prestamosID.Add(dr["prestamo_id"].ToString());
            }
        }

        foreach (string item in prestamosID)
        {
            var resultado = from a in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                            where (a.Field<int>("prestamo_id")).ToString() == item
                            select new {prestamoID = a.Field<string>("prestamo_id")};

            foreach (var valor in resultado)
            {
             //   string x = valor.prestamoID;
            }
        }

        return ds;
}
```

Comment: Run it under the debugger to see what exception is being thrown. You may need to turn on "break on handled exception" (or whatever that's called).

Comment: You may have to go into settings and enable all exceptions as well!

Comment: There are not exception. Only exit from method. I have all exception enable.